# Performance issue in flutter animation

Tags: flutter, drawing

I am animating a line in canvas in flutter.i am using AnimationController to control the animation. When i animating a single line, it is get animated without any lag or performance issue.But when i animate more than 10 lines it  gets struck and lagged when rendering the line.In each frame redraw is getting called inoder to animate the line .How to overcome this issue.

Thanks,
Ashwin

Comment: If you can show your code then please add it.

Comment: `"In each frame redraw is getting called inoder to animate the line "` - post your `CustomPainter` code then

Comment: Find my code in the below link-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276891/animation-is-slow-in-flutter

Comment: @pskink Thanks. I will check